# Why does the identity function sometimes change whether patterns are exhaustive?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings

Consider this GHCi session:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -Wincomplete-patterns -Wincomplete-uni-patterns
Prelude> foo t | (_, _) <- t = "Foo"
Prelude> bar t | (_, _) <- id t = "Foo"
Prelude> baz x | Just _ <- x = "Yes" | Nothing <- x = "No"
Prelude> qux x | Just _ <- id x = "Yes" | Nothing <- id x = "No"

<interactive>:3:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘qux’: Patterns not matched: _
Prelude>
```

Why is `qux` considered incomplete by GHC? Do we really know more about `id x` than we do about `x`? And why isn't `bar` also considered incomplete for the same reason that `qux` is?

Or for a possibly clearer example:

```
foo f x
  | Just _ <- f x = "Yes"
  | Nothing <- f x = "No"

bar f x = case f x of
  Just _ -> "Yes"
  Nothing -> "No"
```

As far as I know, those are exactly equivalent, but the former produces the warning and the latter does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like GHC doesn't consider identical expressions to be the same value in a pattern guard unless the expression is a single binding:

```
Prelude> f | Just x <- Just 1 = "foo" | Nothing <- Just 1 = "bar"

<interactive>:5:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘f’: Guards do not cover entire pattern space
```

This is even more silly, in that it's clear the patterns are exhaustive.  It can't even branch.

I'd say that this is probably the right way to do things, even if it's weird.  It encourages binding the expression to a name, which is helpful for ensuring the expression is only evaluated once.  It's certainly a roundabout way of doing it, though.

As for why you're not getting that error in `bar`, it's because there's only one constructor for pairs. You're matching every possible output of `id t`, even if it's a computed expression.  There's no alternative constructor you haven't matched.

Comment: “Because the expressions are different” – actually they aren't, it's both `id x`.

Comment: For both `(,)` and `Maybe`, the type checker already knows the complete set of data constructors; why is there a difference between one (`(,)` for `(,)`) and two (`Just` and `Nothing` for `Maybe`)?

Comment: I agree with @leftaroundabout here. The one missing piece for me is: Why does it matter whether GHC has simplified away `id`, or even knows what `id` does, given that both patterns are matching the same expression?

Comment: I totally misread the question.  I guess it doesn't even consider whether any expression more complex than a single expression matches.  Will update.

Comment: I have updated the answer to be an answer to the question asked.